# Syntax error when creating directory with spaces, parentheses, apostrophe, and question mark

Tags: bash, syntax, mkdir

I know that this probably has something to do with escaping characters, and that there might be similar questions asked already, but this is a tricky combination that I can't figure out.

On my Plex media server I create a directory for each album. The mkdir command for one of the albums does not work for me:

`mkdir 'Oasis (2) - (What's The Story) Morning Glory?'`

I get an error:

`` bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)' ``

I've tried different combinations of escaping characters and removing some of them to find which ones are problematic, but I still can't figure out how I could properly create a directory with this exact name.

Comment: You may find this site helpful https://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/websites/writing/characters-avoid/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `"` and not `'`.

```
$ mkdir "Oasis (2) - (What's The Story) Morning Glory"
$ 
$ rm Oasis\ \(2\)\ -\ \(What\'s\ The\ Story\)\ Morning\ Glory/ -rf
$
```

You have a `'` in your text so that does not match with the `'`'s around it. You can also use:

```
$ mkdir Oasis\ \(2\)\ -\ \(What\'s\ The\ Story\)\ Morning\ Glory/
```

Escape by adding a `\` in front of each of these: {space} ( ) ' for this specific directory.

When it comes to filenames try to avoid characters that are NOT used on different platforms. Windows has different rules than Linux etc.

- Windows filenames: anything except ASCII's control characters and `\/:*?"<>|`
- Linux, OS-X: anything except null or `/`

Systems might warn about it but some do also remove the invalid character or replace it by a code and when you copy the file back suddenly have 2 versions.

Comment: What do you mean by characters that are not used on different platforms?

Comment: see the alteration.